# Double UITabViewControllers using storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, storyboard

Currently I have a setup with firstTabViewController hosting 5 buttons each loading a table view. When a user selects one of the table cells it opens a secondTabViewController with a set of 4 different tab buttons. I am also embedding a navigation controller.

I have set it up via storyboard and have come up with some issues. Firstly when it loads the secondTabViewController it loads it within the firstTabViewController so I have 2 sets of tab buttons on top of each other. If I change the segue to modal it loads the secondTabViewController correctly but doesn't allow me to use the navigation controller to go back.

Is there a solution to this or should I stop wasting my time with using storyboard and rather just set it up programmatically?

Screenshot: [Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFO9N.png)

Comment: can you post a screen shot of your storyboard?

Comment: @mkral Added screenshot, note only the bottom one is currently in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code when I want to hide a tabbar:
I forgot where I stole it from but I'm pretty sure it was here on SO.

```
- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {


[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
    {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
    } 
    else 
    {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
    }

}

[UIView commitAnimations];





}

- (void) showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
{

    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
    {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

    } 
    else 
    {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
    }


}

[UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your original strategy and then hide the first tab view controller's tab bar when you open your second tab bar view.

Comment: I tried using 'self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;' which worked to hide the firstTabViewControllers and displayed the secondTabViewControllers correctly but unfortunately when I went back I no longer had the firstTabViewControllers due to the secondTabViewControllers not popping off the stack.